# Convert string to Keystore.SecretKey in Android

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-security

i have a string. and i need to convert the string into KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry in android.

so that i can able to store my string into KeyStore using KeyStore.setEntry(,,)

How to convert my string into Keystore.SecretKey?

The below code is for get the entry from keystore.

```
   KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
   ks.load(null);
   KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry(alias, null);
```